# How to build native nodejs modules for launchui?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node.js-addon

I'm building an app using proton-native.
it uses native modules written in C++, for example, keytar.

Proton-native uses a tool named **launchui** to package nodejs app as an executable. It's basically simple wrapper for nodejs with the following structure on windows:

```
- myapp.exe
- node.dll
- app/
- - main.js
- - node_modules/
- - - - keytar/
```

Native modules (node addons) does not work by default for such constructions because node-gyp tool links them against node.exe.
The usual approach is to run something like electron-rebuild, which would compile native modules to a version of node incorporated by electronjs.

However, In case of launchui there are no tools for that yet.

Could someone skilled in node-gyp or C++ linking explain what whould be the best approach to properly re-build native modules for launchui? I keep getting `The specified procedure could not be found` after running electron-rebuild and trying to run the app.

I have used dependencywalker to analyze current dependencies of the keytar.node and it shows that it depends on node.exe, however it should depend on node.dll.